# How to convert WebElement to a string for an 'if' statement in selenium/Java

Tags: java, string, selenium, if-statement, automation

I'm automating a webstore in selenium/Java. If the user hasn't selected the size of a product, a message comes up stating 'this is a required field' next to the size. I'm trying to write an 'if' statement that asserts whether this message is present and the action to take if it is, but I cannot get it to work. It would be something along the lines of this:

```
 WebElement sizeIsRequiredMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#advice-required-entry-select_30765)"));
 WebElement sizeSmallButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#product_info_add > div.add-to-cart > div > button"))

          if (sizeIsRequiredMsg.equals("This is a required field.")) {
              action.moveToElement(sizeSmallButton);
              action.click();
              action.perform();
        }
```

I've tried a few different variations using the 'this is a required field' message as a web element. Not sure if I need to convert the WebElement for the message to a string somehow? Or include a boolean? Can anyone help?

Comment: sizeIsRequiredMsg variable's return type is WebElement so you cannot compare WebElement to String so you have to you sizeIsRequiredMsg.getText() method to fetch the text then you can compare two strings.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `getText()` something like this:

**EDIT** I have added the correct cssSelectors and added `try catch` :

```
WebElement addToCartButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#product_info_add  button")); 
action.moveToElement(addToCartButton); 
action.click(); 
action.perform(); 

try {
    WebElement sizeIsRequiredMsg = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".validation-advice"));
    WebElement sizeSmallButton = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".swatches-container .swatch-span:nth-child(2)"))
    if (sizeIsRequiredMsg.getText() == "This is a required field.") {
          action.moveToElement(sizeSmallButton);
          action.click();
          action.perform();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Exception Occured:", e);
};
```

Hope this helps you!

Comment: This does run now but it still doesn't do what I want it to (click the size small button). Thanks anyway :)

Comment: 'org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified'

Comment: @golfumbrella make sure you import action = `import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;` and creat a new Action var = `Actions action;`

Comment: @golfumbrella you can chain the action like this: `action.moveToElement(sizeSmallButton).click().perform();`

Comment: Yeah I've done all that. I think the problem is still with it reading the 'this is a required field' text. I'm not sure if I'm using the right selector but it seems like I've tried them all

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190011/discussion-between-moshe-slavin-and-golf-umbrella).